# Powershell/Batch network mapped drive

Tags: powershell, batch-file, mapped-drive

I want a powershell/batch script that map a drive on a free letter. Or test letters then map on a free one.

I'm sure there is something easier than this.

```
$tab = @()

$tab = @('A:', 'B:', 'C:', 'D:', 'E:', 'F:', 'G:', 'H:', 'I:', 'J:', 'K:', 'L:', 'M:', 'N:', 'O,:', 'P:', 'Q:', 'R:', 'S:', 'T:', 'U:', 'V:', 'W' ,'X:', 'Y:', 'Z')

for($i = 0;$i -lt 26;$i++){

    if(net use $tab[$i] > $null){
        Write-Host $tab[$i] "`tExists"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host $tab[$i] "`tDoesn't exist"
    }
}
```

I need my PS script to write something in a .bat script. So, 1) in my PS script find free letters then write it to the .bat script like this

`$freeletter | Output-File -Append ....`

or 2) my .bat script does something like that :

```
Is G: free ?
   No Is H: free ?
        Yes : Map It -> $mapdrive_1 = "H:"
              Is I: free ?
                    No  Is J: Free ?
                              Yes : Map it -> $mapdrive_2 = "J:"

#Once it's done I got my ONLY 2 mapped drives
$mapdrive_1
$mapdrive_2

#then i can do
net use $mapdrive_1 "my\path1"
net use $mapdrive_2 "my\path1"
start robocopy $mapdrive_1 $mapdrive_2 /options
net use $mapdrive_1 /DELETE
net use $mapdrive_2 /DELETE

net use $mapdrive_1 "my\path2"
net use $mapdrive_2 "my\path2"
start robocopy $mapdrive_1 $mapdrive_2 /options
net use $mapdrive_1 /DELETE
net use $mapdrive_2 /DELETE
```

Hope you understand what I mean :)

Regards,

Nico.

Comment: with cmd.exe, you can use net use `\\servername\share` this will map the network drive for you using the first free letter. Popd will remove it afterward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will output all free letters, you can then pipe to select-object to get just the first one:

```
ls function:[a-z]: -name | where {-not (get-psdrive $_[0] -ea 0)}
```

Comment: This is just incredible :D Really impressive !

I've just find another solution, but so much longer than yours ^^ with `Get-PSDrive | ?{$_.Root -eq $drive + ":\"}` and `If($list.Root -ne $drive + ":\")` And my bad, i HAVE to do it in batch, because the batch script will be executed as last.
A collegue tell me that `net use * \my\path1 /PERSISTENT:NO` will map a drive without letter, and i'll be able to delete it with `net use * \my\path1 /DELETE`

Can you confirm this ? :)

Thank you @ShayLevy for your clever answer

Nico.

Comment: As far as, in case of *, a letter will be selected for you but it isn't necessarily the first one available..

Comment: Yeah, and if I just remove the * it will mount a temporary drive, without any letter. Thank you alot @ShayLevy

Answer (score 0):

```
$Mapdrive = "\\DRIVE NAME\My\Path\"
```

Using a drive alias as I used about makes the drive letter irrelevant which is particularly handy if for some reason or another the drive letter changes.